# While doing gRPC client-side streaming, how server will behave when it does not receive all of requests

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

I'm wondering about the scenario that the client is going to do data streaming. During that process, it will send three requests. Let's assume that the server will receive only two.

How in current situation server will react? I guess that server will never notify the client about the finished request (it knows the number of requests that are expected) and the process will get terminated as long as the deadline has been defined. Do my assumptions are valid?

I'm working on the Java implementation of gRPC.

Comment: I  write a simple test the server will wait until client completed

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. If the server is waiting for the 3rd request which it never receives, the call will be terminated by the deadline.